# Как правильно подвести итоги конкурса?

Tags: обсуждение, конкурс

Объявил конкурс по своему вопросу. На данный момент три ответа. Раздать баллы, когда он закончится, - не проблема. Но хотелось бы подвести итоги, рассказать о вкладе каждого конкурсанта в решение проблемы, дать пояснения, сказать спасибо, наконец.

Как оптимальнее это сделать? Создать свой ответ? Или дополнить вопрос?

На мой взгляд, создать ответ кажется более логичным и законченным, что ли. Но, может, как в притче о банане и брандспойте, здесь свои правила?

Comment: в ответах должны быть ответы, а не рассказы, пояснения и т.д.

Comment: @Grundy а вдруг автор хочет сделать агрегированный ответ. В котором укажет плюсы/минусы других решений и подобное. Тогда в целом можно.

Answer (score 5):

Думаю да, логичнее создать ответ со сравнением других ответов.

Но принять всё же стоит лучший ответ, а не сравнение.
Кроме случаев, когда из разных частей других ответов собирается что-то цельное новое.

Пример такого ответа со сравнением: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/761170/178988

Comment: Разумеется. Свой ответ не собираюсь принимать, раздавать ему баллы и т.п.  Смысл? :) А вот как итог постфатум он был бы логичен.